# What is wrong with the following MySQL create statement?

Tags: mysql

I am struggling to get this simple table created in MySQL:

```
create table events (
    id int,
    when timestamp not null,
    summary varchar(256) not null,
    description varchar(500) not null,
    owner int not null,
    attendee int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(owner) REFERENCES calendar_users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(attendee) REFERENCES calendar_users(id)
);
```

The description of the FKs are fine and the PK statement. However, MySQL seems to have a problem in the third line for some reason. Could anyone please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: `when` is a reserved word

Comment: what's wrong with the title of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`when` is a reserved word.

To use it as a name, surround it with backticks.

Comment: Or better still, use another identifier.

Comment: It's a *reserved* word. There are several *keywords* that are not *reserved*!

Answer (score 1):

`when` is a reserved word (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)

it would be best just to change the field title.  I use datetime for example

Comment: Of course datetime is exactly the kind of keyword that may, in the future, become "reserved"!!! ;-)